# How to create custom CSS3 loading circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create CSS3 loading circle like this one:

[image]

the inner circle will grow using timer.

the problem what is the technique that I can use to grow the inner circle like this way?

I have this CSS code:

```
.circle {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50px;
background:#fff;
}
```

`.circle` is just a `div`

the outer circle can be used as background image because it will be static. it will never change, only the inner one will change according to timer.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-ajax-loading-icon/

Comment: You might be able to adapt the CSS Tricks demo http://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/

Answer (score 5):

HTML

In this first example, create only two div and thanks to the border-radius property, they will take the circle shape.

```
<div class="ball"></div>
<div class="ball1"></div>
```

CSS

For the CSS style is very simple, just play with the parameters for the graphic you want, as regards the animation simply use the transform:rotateproperty.

```
.ball {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin .5s infinite linear;
}

.ball1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    -moz-animation: spinoff .5s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spinoff .5s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}

@-moz-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoff {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    };
}
```

Second Example CSS3 Loading Animation Loop
HTML

The second example is the same as the precedent for the markup, the main difference you'll find it in the CSS.

```
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle1"></div>
```

CSS

Simply in this example we are going to act on the rotation, and more we insert an animation that will allow us to have an pulse effect.
This effect will be active only in the first circle.

```
.circle {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 35px #2187e7;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -moz-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: spinPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

.circle1 {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,183,229,0.9);
    opacity: .9;
    border-left: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-right: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #2187e7;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    -moz-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spinoffPulse 1s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spinPulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(160deg);
        opacity: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(145deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(-320deg);
        opacity: 0;
    };
}

@-moz-keyframes spinoffPulse {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinPulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(160deg);
        opacity: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2187e7;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(145deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-320deg);
        opacity: 0;
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinoffPulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    };
}
```

Third Example CSS3 Loading Animation Loop
HTML

In this latest example we find a simple loop that is animated thanks to the transform:scale property.
The markup is longer than its predecessors, but this can vary according to the blocks you want to insert.

```
<div id="block_1" class="barlittle"></div>
<div id="block_2" class="barlittle"></div>
<div id="block_3" class="barlittle"></div>
<div id="block_4" class="barlittle"></div>
<div id="block_5" class="barlittle"></div>
```

CSS

Here the style is much easier to handle since we're going to take to apply the effect to animation:delay property of each block.

```
.barlittle {
    background-color: #2187e7;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #2187e7 25%, #a0eaff);
    border-left: 1px solid #111;
    border-top: 1px solid #111;
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-animation: move 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: move 1s infinite linear;
}

#block_1 {
    -moz-animation-delay: .4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

#block_2 {
    -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
}

#block_3 {
    -moz-animation-delay: .2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .2s;
}

#block_4 {
    -moz-animation-delay: .3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
}

#block_5 {
    -moz-animation-delay: .4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0.1;
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
        opacity: 0.1;
    };
}
```

Conclusion

I hope that with this tutorial you learned how to create simple animations loop using only the CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
#floatingCirclesG{
position:relative;
width:128px;
height:128px;
-moz-transform:scale(0.6);
-webkit-transform:scale(0.6);
-ms-transform:scale(0.6);
-o-transform:scale(0.6);
transform:scale(0.6);
}

.f_circleG{
position:absolute;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
height:23px;
width:23px;
-moz-border-radius:12px;
-moz-animation-name:f_fadeG;
-moz-animation-duration:1.04s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-direction:linear;
-webkit-border-radius:12px;
-webkit-animation-name:f_fadeG;
-webkit-animation-duration:1.04s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:linear;
-ms-border-radius:12px;
-ms-animation-name:f_fadeG;
-ms-animation-duration:1.04s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-direction:linear;
-o-border-radius:12px;
-o-animation-name:f_fadeG;
-o-animation-duration:1.04s;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-direction:linear;
border-radius:12px;
animation-name:f_fadeG;
animation-duration:1.04s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:linear;
}

#frotateG_01{
left:0;
top:52px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.39s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.39s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.39s;
-o-animation-delay:0.39s;
animation-delay:0.39s;
}

#frotateG_02{
left:15px;
top:15px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.52s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.52s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.52s;
-o-animation-delay:0.52s;
animation-delay:0.52s;
}

#frotateG_03{
left:52px;
top:0;
-moz-animation-delay:0.65s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.65s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.65s;
-o-animation-delay:0.65s;
animation-delay:0.65s;
}

#frotateG_04{
right:15px;
top:15px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.78s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.78s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.78s;
-o-animation-delay:0.78s;
animation-delay:0.78s;
}

#frotateG_05{
right:0;
top:52px;
-moz-animation-delay:0.91s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0.91s;
-ms-animation-delay:0.91s;
-o-animation-delay:0.91s;
animation-delay:0.91s;
}

#frotateG_06{
right:15px;
bottom:15px;
-moz-animation-delay:1.04s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.04s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.04s;
-o-animation-delay:1.04s;
animation-delay:1.04s;
}

#frotateG_07{
left:52px;
bottom:0;
-moz-animation-delay:1.17s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.17s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.17s;
-o-animation-delay:1.17s;
animation-delay:1.17s;
}

#frotateG_08{
left:15px;
bottom:15px;
-moz-animation-delay:1.3s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.3s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.3s;
-o-animation-delay:1.3s;
animation-delay:1.3s;
}

@-moz-keyframes f_fadeG{
0%{
background-color:#000000}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF}

}

@-webkit-keyframes f_fadeG{
0%{
background-color:#000000}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF}

}

@-ms-keyframes f_fadeG{
0%{
background-color:#000000}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF}

}

@-o-keyframes f_fadeG{
0%{
background-color:#000000}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF}

}

@keyframes f_fadeG{
0%{
background-color:#000000}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF}

}

</style>
<div id="floatingCirclesG">
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_01">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_02">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_03">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_04">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_05">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_06">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_07">
</div>
<div class="f_circleG" id="frotateG_08">
</div>
</div>
```

To create such Loader, you may try http://cssload.net/